# threads or processes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing basically port scanner (not really, but it's close). Pinging machines one by one is just slow, so I definitely need some kind of parallel processing. Bottle neck is definitely network I/O, so I was thinking that threads would suffice (with python's GIL existing), they're easier to use. But would utilization of processes instead bring significant performance increase (15%+)?

Sadly, I don't have time to try both approaches and pick better of them based on some measurements or something :/

Thanks :)

Comment: You could use a concurrent library, Gevent, Greenlet, Twisted...  There's a list of a bunch here http://wiki.python.org/moin/Concurrency/

Comment: If you have time to ask a question on SO and wait for an answer, you have time to try both ways. It takes about 5 seconds to change from, e.g., `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` to `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`, and maybe 30 seconds to write the performance test harness.

Comment: those "Pool" things are really not an option for me, I need more control over individual threads/processes arguments then they offer :/ Otherwise it would be piece of cake :)

Comment: I don't think you really _do_ need control over the thread/process arguments; you need control over the _job_ arguments. If you have 10000 machines to ping, you don't want 10000 threads; you want, say, a pool of 16 threads reading 10000 jobs off a queue.

Comment: well, I need to pass to threads identifiers and sequence ids (as described in ICMP) + ports to listen on.. but maybe I could do this even while using PoolExecutors.. ty for tip :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have time to wait for a performance test, you presumably just want guesses. So:

There's probably no real advantage to `multiprocessing` over `threading` here.

There is a disadvantage to `multiprocessing` in the overhead per task. You can get around that by tuning the batch size, but with `threading`, you don't have to.

So, I'd use threading.

However, I'd do it using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`, so when you get a bit of time later, you can try the one-liner change to `ProcessPoolExecutor` and compare performance.

Comment: those "Pool" things are really not an option for me, I need more control over individual threads/processes arguments then they offer :/ But thanks for opinion, I'll go with threads and will see :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured I'd just post this as a potential answer.
I've used, like Gevent, but another lib would work too.

This is taken from Gevent's website

```
import gevent
from gevent import socket
urls = ['www.google.com', 'www.example.com', 'www.python.org']
jobs = [gevent.spawn(socket.gethostbyname, url) for url in urls]
gevent.joinall(jobs, timeout=2)
[job.value for job in jobs]
```

> ['74.125.79.106', '208.77.188.166', '82.94.164.162']

This will give you a concurrent approach, without the overhead of threads/processes =)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you want the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module to take advantages of extra CPU cores in processing. Since each process gets its own GIL, they can make CPU-intensive calls without regard to whether any particular call locks the GIL for its duration.

From a programming standpoint, the main downside is really that you have far less shared memory. In fact, you can only send data round using shared objects, such as `multiprocessing.Array` or `multiprocessing.Value`. And because so little memory is shared, each time you create another instance, you doubled your memory footprint.

Threads may be a workable option, though if you want maximum efficiency, you should go with an asynchronous approach. There are a number of frameworks for asynchronous network I/O, though the best known is probably [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

Comment: He claims that his code is entirely network-bound. So he doesn't need to take advantage of extra CPU cores.